# WWF SQL persistent schema script for old NET version

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I am looking for SQL Scripts for Windows Workflow Foundation SQL Workflow Instance Store for NET Framework 4.5.1

I know that scripts are located at `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\SQL\en` however i have already upgraded framework to 4.7 so these scripts are new.

I need the one that shipped with .NET Framework 4.5.1

Answer (score 0):

This links to the old scripts:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tuhtu41xq7nujj8/SQLWorkflowInstenceStore.zip?dl=0?dl